# MPAndroidChart homescreen widget

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

is there any example, howto place any of charts in [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to homescreen widget?

//i tried to use getChartbitmap(), but 
1)bitmap is not created immediately after calling invalidate(), so it return null
2)i dont see way, howto initialize chart class without placing  resources - which i cant do 
for widget.

anybody have some successful example ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
BarData chartData =...
BarChart chart = new BarChart(mContext);
chart.setData(chartData);

chart.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(300,View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
              View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500,View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
chart.layout(0, 0, chart.getMeasuredWidth(), chart.getMeasuredHeight());

Bitmap chartBitmap = chart.getChartBitmap();
```

Comment: Thank you! The measuring is important!

Answer (score 3):

The chart needs some milliseconds to draw the content onto the `Bitmap`. That is the reason why calling `getChartBitmap()` right after `invalidate()` will not return a valid `Bitmap`.

Try using a `Handler` and delay the time before retrieving the `Bitmap` by abound 100ms.

Comment: thank you, it works.   To finalize answer for my question i still need more help :/   .objective is to have homescreen widget. Therefore i cant use main activity to inicialize.   so when i call i.e mChart = new LineChart(context);
        setData(45, 100); (tis is function from your exampls..) and after while call getChartBitmap, i still get error "   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0"    any idea? I am trying to use inflanter, layouts, but nothing was working so far

Comment: Did you get any answer for this, because i am also getting the same error that width height should be greater than zero

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda Is this still the best solution? Has a callback been introduced when the chart layout is complete?

Answer (score -2):

In Activity with chart, function getChartBitmap() working fine! It's return bitmap without any errors. IMHO that's the problem, in widget we don't have an activity, placing created chart in layout is not take effect :( So, we can't have a widget with this chart at all, and it's very sad - this chart so really cool.